# About the “degré de figement” of “syntagmes figés”

Tags: linguistique, mots-composés

What “degré de figement” do words such as *mauvaise herbe*, *grand magasin* and *pomme de terre* have? Is it “figement complet” or “partiel”?

What is the best strategy to determine whether an expression is a “figement complet” or a “figement partiel”?

Why is *rouge-gorge* a “syntagme libre”?

Comment: [Information](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_%28linguistique%29).

Comment: Vous trouverez les règles persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/… ; à vous de les interpréter... pour moi rouge-gorge est un oiseau discret et charmant, à l’œil vif qui protège son territoire... chaque formulation d'une réalité est singulière ; rouge-gorge 3° de la page 61

Comment: Is this question really a better fit here than on Linguistics ? Knowing what linguistic theory OP has in mind when asking about "figement complet" and "partiel" would help.

Comment: Also, it sounds like homework. What have you tried ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to fit better on linguistics, even though the language discussed is indeed french.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about how frozen are some [multiword expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiword_expression).

[*Pomme de terre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pomme%20de%20terre) is a lexeme in itself, so much more frozen than the others that it might not even be in the same category.
*Mauvaise herbe* and *grand magasin* are completely frozen, as far as I can tell (*figement complet*).

I found some theory [here¹](http://stl.recherche.univ-lille3.fr/siteheberges/masterLSF/memoires/2011_Ledee.pdf) (page 9ff.), that answers your second question.

Basically, if you can fiddle a bit with the expression, inserting words, changing some for synonyms, etc., it's only partially frozen.

---

¹ masters thesis of Corinne Lédée (2011)